# Eclipse can't open class declarations

Tags: eclipse, class, declaration

### [This is what happens when I try to open the declaration of Thread.class](http://postimg.org/image/kfme2dk5f/)

I'm using Eclipse Standard/SDK

Version: Kepler Service Release 1
Build id: 20130919-0819

### How could I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the big button in the error and find the source code.

The JDK source is typically in `Program Files\Java\jdk...\src.zip`.